# XAML colour binding converter from bool not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I'm trying to change the text colour in a `datagrid` depending on a `bool` in my model using a converter but I get the following error.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement
> or FrameworkContentElement for target element.
> BindingExpression:Path=DiameterCustom; DataItem=null; target element
> is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=7886611); target property is
> 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

Does anyone know why this is?

My xaml is as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <conv:UnitConverter x:Key="UnitConverter"></conv:UnitConverter>
    <conv:CustomColourConverter x:Key="CustomColourConverter"></conv:CustomColourConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn 
  Header="Diameter &#x0a;(mm)"  
  Binding="{Binding Diameter, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:n0}, Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}, ConverterParameter=1000}" 
  Foreground="{Binding DiameterCustom, Converter={StaticResource CustomColourConverter}}"/>
```

This is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool v = (bool)value;

    if (v == true)
    {            
       //return return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
       return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);            
    }

  //return return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
  return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and just for completeness, here is my model property:

```
private bool diameterCustom;

public bool DiameterCustom
{
   get { return diameterCustom; }
   set { SetAndNotify(ref this.diameterCustom, value); }
}
```

Note, the data binding for Diameter and the unit converter work fine.

Comment: It doesn't make sens - only Binding attribute binds per item of collection... Other properties would rather bind from global datacontext... You prolly need to do this via style trigger... Googling"datagrid WPF color per cell" should returns duplicate

Comment: You could expose a string as a property from a viewmodel and use the brushconverter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.brushconverter?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 or you could use a datatrigger as selvin suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the help both. I've had a play and got it working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the text colour cell by cell the following solution worked:

```
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Header="Diameter &#x0a;(mm)"  
    Binding="{Binding Diameter, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat={}{0:n0}, Converter={StaticResource UnitConverter}, ConverterParameter=1000}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding DiameterCustom, Converter={StaticResource CustomColourConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```